# Fixing Edge Gaps in ML Classification of Mosaiced Landsat8 Imagery using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic

I have mosaic-ed four Landsat8 images in ArcMap to cover an area over and west of Denver and Colorado Springs, Colorado:

```
LC08_L1TP_033032_20200406_20
LC08_L1TP_033033_20200406_20
LC08_L1TP_033033_20200429_20
LC08_L1TP_033032_20200429_20
```

The Mosaic appears to work well, but with a slight visible difference at the boundary between images from different dates.

When I run a Maximum Likelihood Classification on the mosaic (shown), the there is no classified output along what were the eastern and western edges bands of the pre-mosaic-ed images.  This is no problem for this project where it occurs at the westernmost and easternmost edges of my mosaic-ed image, but it results in an unclassified strip right down the near-middle of my classified output.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image: Mosaic-ed and classified output]

Answer (score 1):

I removed the two Thermal Bands 10 and 11 from the Composite Rasters used in the mosaic, re-ran, and this appears to have worked.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot imbedded in your post rather than an external link to a screenshot? This will help your question remain valid when the link inevitably goes 404.